# C# Ungreedy Regex swallows newline

Tags: c#, regex, string, newline, non-greedy

**Background:**
    Match MyMatch1 = Regex.Match("Line1\nLine2\n", "^.*$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match MyMatch2 = Regex.Match("Line1\nLine2\n", "^.*?$", RegexOptions.Singleline);

> MyMatch1.Groups[0].Value.Length => "Line1\nLine2\n"
>   MyMatch2.Groups[0].Value.Length => "Line1\nLine2"

Why does the non-greedy variant (`.*?`) remove the newline char at the end of the string?
Because my Regular Expression starts with `^` and ends with `$` the non-greedy variant should also take the full string.

**Problem:**
As I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575315/c-sharp-system-regex-matches-lf-when-it-should-not) a `$` is also finding a `\n`.

```
string sStr1 = "Line1\nLine2\nOptionalLine\n";
string sStr2 = "Line1\nLine2\n";
string sRegex = "^(.*?)(OptionalLine\n)?$"; // <= I need non-greedy here
Match MyMatch3 = Regex.Match(sStr1, sRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline);  
Match MyMatch4 = Regex.Match(sStr2, sRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

> MyMatch3.Groups[1].Value => 'Line1\nLine2\n'
>   MyMatch3.Groups[2].Value => 'OptionalLine3\n'
>
> MyMatch4.Groups[1].Value => 'Line1\nLine2'  **<= I want to have a newline here!**
>   MyMatch4.Groups[2].Value => ''

What can I do to get the newline even if the OptionalLine is missing?
How should I write my Regex to achieve this?

Comment: Because `$` matches a position before the final newline in a string. Since the second `.*?` is non-greedy, the `$` is tried first, and only if it does not match, `.*?` is expanded to advance to the next position, hence, `$` matches earlier. Use `\z` instead of `$` to get consistent behavior.

Comment: Thank you - \z was the solution - even to my now updated question.