# Regular expressions: validate that string only contains instances of pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that only matches when a string consists of instances of some pattern. Let's say that I only need a string to consist of "foo" or "bar" substrings separated by a space.

So, valid instances are: "foo", "bar", "foo foo", "foo bar", "foo foo bar", "foo bar foo bar"...
Invalid instances: "foofoo bar", "baz foo bar", "foo bar baz"

Thus, each instance of foo or bar (i.e. my base pattern or capture group), should be preceded by either a space or be at the start of string, and it should be ended either with a space, or be located at the end of the string.

It seemed like a simple task, but I can't figure it out.

This is what I got so far:

```
(?:^|bar\s|foo\s)(foo|bar)(?=$|\sbar|\sfoo)
```

It doesn't work on "foofoo bar" (somehow it's valid).

I'm testing it in Python. But it would be good if it worked in JS too.

Comment: You seem to want to match whitespace separated patterns, `^(?:foo|bar)(?: (?:foo|bar))*$`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you, that worked. Can I do anything to specify my pattern only once? I would like to use a complex pattern. Could named groups and \g<id> be applied here?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a pattern like

```
^(?:foo|bar)(?: (?:foo|bar))*$
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/emU8gG/1)

If your regex engine supports recursive patterns you may  use

```
^(?<id>foo|bar)(?: (?&id))*$
```

See [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/emU8gG/2)

NOTE:

- If you have a problem with a trailing newline matched, you need to adjust the end of string anchor (see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575971/3832970))
- If you need to allow any 1+  whitespace chars between the entries, use `\s+`. If the whitespace should not match line breaks use `\h+` or `[\p{Zs}\t]+`. If there can only be 1 whitespace between the entries remove the `+`.
- To allow leading/trailing whitespace, add the `\s*` / `\h*` / `[\p{Zs}\t]*` after `^` and before `$`.

Comment: Thank you. Could that recursive pattern functionality be reproduced with ECMA Script flavour? I'm trying to adapt your example, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @RayP. ECMAScript does not support recursion. If you work in JS, just [build the pattern dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553431/3832970).

Comment: unfortunatelly, I have to use this pattern in a JSON schema, so I would not be able to build it dynamically. Nonetheless, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: NOTE: For cases where a pattern can repeat one or more times, just use `^(?:pattern)+$`. If there can be whitespaces inside, just put `\s*` where expected. E.g. `^(?:\s*BLAH\s*\d+)+\s*$` to match and validate `BLAH123BLAH    456789    BLAH1` with trailing/leading spaces.